# How to enable conditionally validation using ValidationEngine

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validation-engine

I am using ValidationEngine for client side validation. I have a scenario

In my form I have 3 text box, now I want to validate "required" on all the field only if any one of them is filled, else I can proceed with blank form

How do I do this using Jquery validationEngine

Answer (score 4):

You must use condRequired to set a conditional validation. This is also useful if you want to use chekboxes. Below I put the example of the use:

```
<input value="" type="text" name="field1" id="fieldToCheck" />
<input class="validate[condRequired[fieldToCheck]]" type="text" id="field2" name="fieldRequiredIfFiel1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for ValidationEngine it doesn't look like it supports optional validation. I would suggest using [lightweight validation plugin](https://github.com/sinemetu1/jquery-lightweight-validation) or [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Comment: it does ! it provides a `condRequired` method for conditional validation.

Comment: @Amyth Not sure if this was a feature or not in February when I answered the question. If it was it wasn't documented well. Anyway [here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#condrequired) is a link to it for future reference.

Comment: yeah i am sorry, i realized that they have introduced it in version 2.6 and it wasn't a feature until then. My bad.